# NetBeans can not start Tomcat on mac

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, netbeans

I am trying to run Tomcat using NetBeans on Mac. When I execute `startup.sh` in `bin` folder and then access `http://localhost:8080` everything looks great. Then I tried running my JAVA project in NetBeans, but it said that port 8080 is already in use. So I found which process is running on this port using `lsof -i :8080` and killed it (or executed `shutdown.sh` in `bin` folder, it is the same).

Then I tried to run my project in NetBeans and after over 3 minutes of waiting it says this

```
.../WebApplication/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1045: Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed.
```

There is log:

```
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.183 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.4
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.196 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jan 18 2018 19:42:17 UTC
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.199 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.4.0
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.200 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.201 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.13.1
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.201 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.201 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.201 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_161-b12
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.201 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.201 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/patrikbujna/lib/Apache-Tomcat-Netbeans/9.0.4
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.202 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/patrikbujna/lib/apache-tomcat-9.0.4
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.203 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/patrikbujna/lib/Apache-Tomcat-Netbeans/9.0.4/conf/logging.properties
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.203 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.203 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|Patriks-MacBook-Pro.local
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.204 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.204 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.205 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.206 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/patrikbujna/lib/Apache-Tomcat-Netbeans/9.0.4
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.207 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/patrikbujna/lib/apache-tomcat-9.0.4
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.208 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/patrikbujna/lib/Apache-Tomcat-Netbeans/9.0.4/temp
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.208 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/patrikbujna/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.579 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.619 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.637 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.638 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.641 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1337 ms
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.4
09-Feb-2018 01:07:06.719 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor [/Users/patrikbujna/lib/Apache-Tomcat-Netbeans/9.0.4/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml]
09-Feb-2018 01:07:07.121 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor [/Users/patrikbujna/lib/Apache-Tomcat-Netbeans/9.0.4/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml] has finished in [401] ms
09-Feb-2018 01:07:07.121 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor [/Users/patrikbujna/lib/Apache-Tomcat-Netbeans/9.0.4/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml]
09-Feb-2018 01:07:07.142 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor [/Users/patrikbujna/lib/Apache-Tomcat-Netbeans/9.0.4/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml] has finished in [21] ms
09-Feb-2018 01:07:07.147 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Feb-2018 01:07:07.156 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Feb-2018 01:07:07.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 515 ms
```

Can you guys help me? I do not know what to solve this several days...

Comment: until you share complete server log, it is impossible to say

Comment: och sorry, my bad.. it is updated

Comment: it says `Server startup in 515 ms`. Then what is your question?

Comment: that is the point.. log looks ok, but build of application failed with Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed.

Comment: I don't see that error here ? where are you getting that error ?

Comment: there is a screen of output for better understanding

https://imgur.com/a/oWSNY

Comment: @P.May In Netbeans goto Tools -> Options -> and select No Proxy (if you're not behind the proxy server)

Answer (score 1):

From the Comments:

> In Netbeans, go to Tools -> Options -> and select No Proxy (if you're not behind the proxy server)

- [Shashanth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5180017/shashanth)

To resume this for both Mac OS and Windows:

- on Mac: Go to Netbreans Preferences, and there choose "No Proxy".
- on Windows, Go to Tools, then Options, and there choose "No Proxy".

I'm answering this so other users with the same problem can easily determine the answer that was provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing XAMPP for mac it explicitly runs the server for you to run your application or you can try with Apache Tomee server.
XAMPP: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html
TOMEE: http://tomee.apache.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

What my problem was I was using wrong jdk version for netbeans. For example, I was using jdk version java-1.8 with netbeans 12. I changed the JDK version to the latest and tried running tomcat again and it started working.

It took me a week to figure this thing out. All the other options didn't work for me.